# could anyone help me? these code are wired(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input())
name = []
T = {}

for i in range(n):
    data = input().split(" ")
    if data[2] not in name:
        name.append(data[2])
        T[data[2]] = {}
    T[data[2]][data[0]] = data[1]
    print(T)
```

input these:

4

key2 1 A

key3 2 B

key1 5 A

key1 5 B

when I remove "name.append(data[2])",I got

```
{'A'：{'key2'：'1'}}
{'A'：{'key2'：'1'}，'B'：{'key3'：'2'}}
{'A'：{'key1'：'5'}，'B'：{'key3'：'2'}}
{'A'：{'key1'：'5'}，'B'：{'key1'：'5'}}
```

if not, I got

```
{'A'：{'key2'：'1'}}
{'A'：{'key2'：'1'}，'B'：{'key3'：'2'}}
{'A'：{'key2'：'1'，'key1'：'5'}，'B'：{'key3'：'2'}}
{'A'：{'key2'：'1'，'key1'：'5'}，'B'：{'key3'：'2'，'key1'：'5'}}
```

Why?

Comment: THX eyeryone!!! I know now

Answer (score 1):

When `name.append(data[2])` is removed `T[data[2]][data[0]] = data[1]` is getting overwritten every time in the loop so you are getting the last values in `T`.

Answer (score 0):

> when I remove `name.append(data[2])`

Your code is using `name` to determine whether or not your `A` or `B` key in `T` needs to be created anew. If you stop keeping track of this, it creates them anew every time, so only the very last change is visible (as all the previous ones were thrown out).

As an aside, you can remove the `name` variable entirely, by changing your `if` condition from `data[2] not in name` to `data[2] not in T`. Using `in` to check if something is in a dictionary checks only the keys of that dictionary, which is what you would want here.